# Include all remaining fields in RailsAdmin group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

When used outside of a group block, `include_all_fields` will render all of the remaining fields which have not been written explicitly in the CRUD action block.

Is there a way to use the method `include_all_fields` in a RailsAdmin group? Or somehow render all remaining fields, which haven't been rendered in other groups in the same CRUD action block?

e.g.

```
module DummyAdmin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rails_admin do
      edit do
        group :first_group do
          field :some_field
        end

        group :second_group do
          field :another_field
          field :yet_another_field
        end

        group :group_containing_all_other_fields do
          include_all_fields # this renders an error
          # I'm looking for some other way to render all remaining fields inside this group block
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have to define them manually, you could use some metaprogramming to do it, if you are willing i could add an answer with that approach.

Comment: In the end, I did define the fields manually. Feel free to add an answer with a metaprogramming approach. It would be interesting to see what you come up with :)